# getting text from edit text in input dialog

Tags: android, text, dialog, alert, edit

I have an alert dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setText(sp.getString("NAME_0",""),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(input);
    String name = input.getText().toString();
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter your name"); //Set the title of the box
    //alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(""); //Set the message for the box
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.cancel(); //when they click dismiss we will dismiss the box
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog =alertDialogBuilder.create(); //create the box
    alertDialog.show(); //actually show the box
```

And the problem is that 'name' always seems to be empty. Is there a different way to get the text from an edit text that is inside an alert dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method works fine you are just assigning the variable too soon, you need to do it for example when the user clicks the button inside the onClick()

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);
EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setText(sp.getString("NAME_0",""),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(input);
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter your name"); //Set the title of the box
//alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(""); //Set the message for the box
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        String name = input.getText().toString();
        dialog.cancel(); //when they click dismiss we will dismiss the box
    }
});
AlertDialog alertDialog =alertDialogBuilder.create(); //create the box
alertDialog.show(); //actually show the box
```

You were trying to the value of the EdtiText at the time of creation of the dialog, which is empty.